# jasmine maven plugin ReferenceError: "define" is not defined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, maven, jasmine, pom.xml

I'm trying to integrate jasmine in my maven project but I'm always getting this error: ReferenceError: "define" is not defined.

I have a simple test:

```
 define("activerequests", function(example) {
  describe("activerequests", function() {
    it("should return active requestss", function() {
      expect(getActiveRequests).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

my pom looks like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jsSrcDir>src/main/webapp/</jsSrcDir>
                    <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <include>services/jquery/jquery.js</include>
                        <include>services/jquery-mobile/jquery-mobile.js</include>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                    <jsTestSrcDir>src/test/javascript/jasmine/spec</jsTestSrcDir> <!-- Define your Test source Dir -->
                    <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                    <browserVersion>FIREFOX_3</browserVersion>
                    <serverPort>8234</serverPort>
                    <specDirectoryName>specs</specDirectoryName>
                    <specIncludes>
                        <include>test.js</include>
                    </specIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I'm stuck.

Can you help me?